# Could you please explain the meaning of "skyline" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Of the parks 1466 Acres Memorial Park has a 18 hole golf course, bike or walking trails and other things to occupy your entertainment style. It's often hosts  annual events which are seen in the video and also features a few views of **Uptown Houston's Skyline.**

Whenever it comes to the skyline I have a great deal of difficulty understanding the context.

Answer (score 4):

The writing in the passage is very poor. It doesn't make much sense. It was either copied incorrectly, or it was written by someone who was subliterate (that is, someone who doesn't know how to read and write very well).

Anyway, one of the meanings of **a view** is:

> the things that you can see from a place : *There was a lovely view of the lake from the bedroom window.*
>
> (From [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/view_1?q=view).)

**[Uptown Houston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptown_Houston)** is a place. That's its name.

A **skyline** is:

> the pattern that is made against the sky by tall buildings : *the New York skyline*
>
> (From [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/skyline?q=skyline).)

So, **a view of Uptown Houston's skyline** would look something like this:

[image]

<sup>"Uptown Houston" by Henry Han - Own work. Licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Maybe you can see such a view from the golf course (it's not clear to me from the writing). I don't know why they said "a few views". That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would have been a +1 but for the first paragraph, which is gratuitously criticising the quoted passage but not adding anything useful to the answer. That part could have been left as a separate comment on the question if you really felt it needed to be said.

Comment: @ClickRick, if you are trying to read something in a foreign language, and the thing you are trying to read is badly written and doesn't make sense, then it's really, really useful to know that.

Answer (score 0):

the outline of buildings, mountains, etc., against the background of the sky.

http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/skyline